# Measuring temperature at submicron resolution

Tags: experimental-physics, temperature, thermal-radiation, microscopy, instrument

Do we have any microscopic technique/protocol to measure temperature at sub-micron resolution?

Comment: what have you done to answer that question?

Answer (score 0):

One of the optical tools is quantum dots that change color (spectrum) with temperature. These can be imaged with conventional microscopy (which is [diffraction-limited](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffraction-limited_system) around 300nm) or super-resolution techniques ([STED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STED_microscopy) can provide 50-100nm resolution)

For example, QDot655 as [demonstrated here](https://journals.physiology.org/doi/full/10.1152/jn.00275.2016) in biological sample shifts spectrum with temperature at a rate of 0.119nm / deg C between 28C and 43C

[image: qdot 655 shifts spectrum with increase in temperature]

Answer (score 0):

[Frances Hellman's research page](https://www.researchgate.net/scientific-contributions/F-Hellman-9098219/publications/2) has various papers on a nanocalorimeter.

Take a silicon wafer and deposit a thin film of silicon nitride on it. Then very carefully dissolve a window all the way through the substrate from the back side, leaving the thin film intact. You now have a free standing thin film well under 1$\mu$ thick, supported by the edges.

The deposit a couple wires on the thin film. One is a resistor to add heat. The other is a temperature sensor. Deposit a thin film you want to test.

You can now add known amounts of heat to a nanogram sample and measure the temperature rise.

Variation on the theme: measure the heat output of a single living cell.